# Views settings Menu Tabs not working

Tags: views, 8

**I think module views have problem with menu tabs.**

I was created a simple views with settings menu tabs like this.

#### Custom view for user

> [image]

#### Custom path

> [image]

#### Settings menu Tabs

> [image]

#### Contextual filter and settings

> [image]
>
> [image]

After i go to url: examples.com/user/1/display  and get error

> RuntimeException: Callable
> "Drupal\contact\Access\ContactPageAccess::access" requires a value for
> the "$user" argument. in
> Drupal\Component\Utility\ArgumentsResolver->handleUnresolvedArgument()
> (line 142 of core/lib/Drupal/Component/Utility/ArgumentsResolver.php).

and url examples.com/user/1 with error:

> Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\MissingMandatoryParametersException:
> Some mandatory parameters are missing ("arg_0") to generate a URL for
> route "view.user.page_1". in
> Drupal\Core\Routing\UrlGenerator->doGenerate() (line 171 of
> core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/UrlGenerator.php).

I was doing something wrong? Can you help me?

Answer (score 3):

This a documentation error.

The correct path for users is `user/%user/display`

In case of nodes should be `node/%node/something`

Answer (score 0):

the view considers 'user' as a parameter in your custom path, so instead make use of

> 'users/%/display'

Hope this will help you.

Comment: That's not what I want. I want menu tabs same with url of user. Example user/1, user/1/edit, user/1/shortcuts.